# Handling the exception at the calling class itself

Tags: java, error-handling

I have a function which calls another function in a different class which throws an exception based on the paraameter provided. I want

```
public class A {
    public int f(int p){
    {
         B obj = new B();
         obj.g(p);
    }
}

public class B {
    public int g(int p)
    {
        // throws an exception for this value of p
    }
}
```

Is it possible that I can catch the exception in `class A` itself and handle it ? I can't change the implementation of `class B`.

Comment: Use a `try-catch` around the `g()` method call.

Comment: Sure you can. What made you suspect you can't?  Is the real problem more complex than you presented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah just use a try-catch statement.

```
public class A {
    public int f(int p){
    {
         B obj = new B();
         try {
             obj.g(p);
         } catch ( /* the exception */ ) {
             // handle the exception
         }
    }
}

public class B {
    public int g(int p)
    {
        // throws an exception for this value of p
    }
}
```